# Difference between IEEE754.h and IEEE854.h

Tags: c, header-files, ieee-754

I'm trying to compile some old source code which makes use of both ieee754.h and ieee854.h in it's Make dependencies.

Problem is, I can't find ieee854.h in any new, official repositories. From what I understood, ieee754.h superseded 854.

Now, I'm not sure whether to just copy and paste ieee854.h from somewhere else and use it, replace it instead with 754, or deleted links to 854 altogether

Comment: if your program is using those two include files you will probably need their libraries as well.  My advice is to get both packages.  If you can't get them you'll have to refactor your code based upon what is available.

Comment: Neither of the headers you name are part of the C standard library, nor even of the POSIX C library.  Therefore, there's little we can say unless you can identify *which* headers of those names the original code relied upon, and which header or headers of those names are available to you now.

Comment: Ultimately, even having information about the headers may not be sufficient, as the answer could depend on how your code uses their contents.  That boils down to the usual requirement: provide a [mcve] to which we can address an answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger they both do the same stuff. IEEE754 is better. I've solved it anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Since IEEE754 superseded 854, it only made sense to remove any links to 854 and keep the 754 calls, or replace them with 754.

I also changed some floating point and math functions inside files requiring them as there were some errors.

Everything compiles and works as it should now.